# Some scripts not loading in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have the following script tags ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draperp/mPQ8Q/))

```
<script src="//tags.mediaforge.com/js/1180"></script>
<script src="//s.adroll.com/j/roundtrip.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script src="//i.kissmetrics.com/i.js"></script>
```

The first two don't load. I get the following errors in the Dev Tools console:
[image]

And the following appears under "Other" in the Network tab:

[image]

And here are the headers for the first one (notice there is no response):

[image]

When I open the same page in incognito, it works and the headers are different

[image]

I've reproduced this with Chrome 30 and 31.0.1650.57 (both 64-bit) on Ubuntu 12.04. Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m on by Windows 7 VM works fine. I've had some people able to reproduce this and some not.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: Disable all extensions and run it. Does it run fine?

Comment: @epascarello, I can't believe I didn't think to try that. AdBlock was blocking them. :P Thanks.

Comment: Try putting the `src`s directly into your address bar. At least that will tell you if you can access the files. Unfortunately, it won't solve the problem. Also, clear your Browser cache, just in case there was some kind of cache failure where the script loaded to memory with a problem.